# How to get BlueImp jQuery FileUpload to generate unique filenames

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I currently have an ASP.NET MVC project that is using BlueImp jQuery FileUploader which works great.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

However, it appears that the default behaviour is to use the original filenames when uploading files to the server. Ideally, what I would like is to have the jQuery FileUploader generate a unique filename for each file uploaded.

I did try performing a rename of each uploaded file on the server, but I then realised that the FileUploader seems to hang on to the original filenames.

Is there a way of making the jQuery uploader generate a random/unique filename for each image uploaded (whether that be individually or as a batch)?

Answer (score 13):

I just had the same issue.  Using the upload.class file for PHP I added a unique file name to the handle_file_upload method like so:

before:

```
$file->name = $this->trim_file_name($name, $type, $index);
```

after:

```
$file->name = $this->trim_file_name(md5($name), $type, $index);
```

I'm sure you can do something similar in ASP.NET

---

**EDIT:**

In the latest version it is on line 506 in UploadHandler.php, change:

```
$name = $this->trim_file_name($file_path, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range);
```

To

```
$name = $this->trim_file_name($file_path, md5($name), $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range);
```

Works perfect!

Comment: Unfortunately, I've seen mention of this handle_file_upload method on my searches in google also, but cannot find any reference to such a method within the jquery files that were contained within the BlueImp .NET project I downloaded - My JS knowledge is pretty bad too unfortunately.

Comment: This is the best answer... I've edited it though to match the latest set of files in Bluimp File Upload. [But it got rejected... So I added it as a comment below]

Answer (score 1):

```
  protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
        $index = null, $content_range = null) {
            $file = new stdClass();
 }
```

before:

```
$file->name = $this->get_file_name($name, $type, $index, $content_range);
```

after:

```
$file->name = $this->get_file_name(uniqid(), $type, $index, $content_range);
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited Paul's answer but it got rejected... Anyway, his answer is correct but the line of code is for an old file.

In the latest version it is on line 506 in UploadHandler.php, change:

```
 $name = $this->trim_file_name($file_path, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range);
```

To

```
 $name = $this->trim_file_name($file_path, md5($name), $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range);
```

Works perfect!